# Immunofluoresence and vaccines

Tags: virology

Can you use indirect immounofluoresence to verify if a vaccine will work against a virus?

Using the vaccine antibodies against the virus, plus a second antibody with fluorophore that will join the first.

Comment: I don't think that experiment would prove that the immune system will be sufficiently stimulated by your vaccine to elict the desired response.

Answer (score 1):

A vaccine isn't antibodies.  It's bits of virus or microbe that elicits a response from the immune system, the most important component being the creation of specific memory cells which are ready to react if the real invader is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an immunoassay like a homogeneous sandwich FRET assay: You can use donor-dye-labelled fluorophore antibodies that are able to recognise specific antigens on the virus to bind the virus antigen, then introduce a second set of antibodies labelled with acceptor-dye fluorophore. If the vaccine works and produces an immune response in the in-vivo model that destroys the virus, the antigen that joins the donor-labelled and acceptor-labelled antibodies is also destroyed and can no longer “sandwich” the two antibodies close together within the Förster distance to exhibit FRET.